# Android Spinner with no selected text - arrow only

Tags: android

I would like to create a spinner which only displays the drop-down arrow and not the selected value and is only the width of the arrow. You can see various examples of this in Android itself e.g. Settings->Display->Brightness (**Edit:** a commenter has pointed out that this is a DialogPreference, but I would like a similar effect using a spinner).

I have attached to the `setOnItemSelectedListener` event and set the selected text to null, but this does not decrease the width of the spinner and you can can briefly see the selected text flicker before it is set to null.

How can I do this with the spinner? Is the spinner the correct control to be using in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no spinner arrow in Settings->Display->Brightness, at least for stock Android 2.2 (as seen on the Nexus One, for example).

Comment: On stock 2.2 I see a spinner looking control to the right of the Brightness text, same with animation and many others. I read in another post that it was a spinner. If it is not a spinner what is it, an imaged button which displays a dialog? At this stage I would prefer to avoid imaged buttons as I don't want to have to hunt for icons. Thanks.

Comment: What you see is a Preference (actually, a DialogPreference of some kind). This is using a widget that has a similar appearance but is not a Spinner.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to ask if I can get a Spinner to look like a DialogPreference as  I don't think using a ListPreference or similar Preference is suitable for my situation.

Comment: This is another thread of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612303/only-show-the-arrowbutton-of-a-spinner. Hope it helps!