# Customizing PreferenceActivity or create my own?

Tags: android

I need screen to setup typical stuff. But I have couple requirements:

1. Preferences stored in DB
2. I need to have some preferences read/only if administrator sets them and prohibit user from changing (from server side)

So, I like built-in functionality but want to save/load from DB and want to disable controls if needed.

Can I do stuff like this or I'm better off with my own activity and Dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both of those. You can extend a `PreferenceActivity` and then override the `getSharedPreferences()` method to return your own implementation of `SharedPreferences` that  saves data into the database instead of into the shared preferences XML. You can provide a preference XML just like you would in the "normal" case, you would just add some code to enable/disable the preferences that you need.

It will take a bit of work to figure out all the parts, but you will save time trying to implement the UI and deal with all the interactions.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836132/howto-make-a-layout-similar-to-the-ones-in-settings/5836291#5836291).