# Preferences layout for non preferneces data

Tags: android

I have an activity which is used for editing some object. Currently its layout as a simple form but I'd like it to be more similar to preferences activity. I'd like to use the same layouts which are available there (e.g. CheckBoxPreference) but save changes to my object rather than to preferences. Is there an easy way to have an activity which looks like preferences but doesn't use preferences at the back back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using next 2 steps:

1. Set preference to be not persistent via [`android:persistent="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3apersistent) in xml or via [`setPersistent(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setPersistent%28boolean%29) in code. This way default `SharedPreferences` will not be modified when user changes values in preference UI.
2. Handle value changes via `OnPreferenceChangeListener` listener registered using [`setOnPreferenceClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29). This will allow you to intercept changes and handle them the way you need.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd option makes sense to me since I have another global preferences page which is persistent and needs to be this way

Comment: Hi sorry for raising a year old comment but is this generally a good way to code or should I code forms from scratch? I also would like the idea of simply using the preferences forms which conform automatically to the OS theme rather than manually creating forms + themes from scratch. thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide your own implementation of `SharedPreferences` and save your data to somewhere that is not preferences, while still using the same UI and XML definition. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836132/howto-make-a-layout-similar-to-the-ones-in-settings/5836291#5836291), and [this link](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/source/browse/trunk/connectbot/src/org/connectbot/HostEditor.java?r=54). The sample link is pretty complex since it is writing data back to the database directly, but it's very easy to replace with a plain `Map` and then retrieve the data from the Map into your object. Or, if you want the data saved immediately, just write it straight into your object.